# Null values in properties passed through storyboard segue

Tags: ios6, null, storyboard, segue

So a little history.  This is working code in an app I've published.  It worked flawlessly before iOS 6 and now will not work.  I figured out a total hack that works but is not ideal so I'm turning to Stackoverflow for some answers.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GoogleSegue"])
    {
        Band *thisBand = self.band;
        NSString *googleSearchString = thisBand.bandLinks.googleSearchLink;
        NSURL *googleSearchUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:googleSearchString];
        WebViewController *webViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        webViewController.delegate = (id)self;
        webViewController.url = googleSearchUrl;
        webViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Google";

    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YouTubeSegue"])
    {

        Band *thisBand = self.band;
        NSString *youTubeString = thisBand.bandLinks.youTubeLink;
        NSURL *youTubeUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:youTubeString];

        WebViewController *webViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        webViewController.delegate = (id)self;
        webViewController.url = youTubeUrl;

/*This is the magic line, if I comment this out, the values showing up in the 
destination view controller's properties are null.  If I have this NSLog uncommented 
everything works flawlessly.  Does anyone have an explanation? */

    NSLog(@"%@%@", webViewController.url, youTubeUrl);
        webViewController.navigationItem.title = @"You Tube";
}
```

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion here I'd appreciate it.  This is a live app that was working fine before iOS6.  It works on my phone when installed from XCode but doesn't not work on release.